# How to return value with E.F. IDbSet<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have **ASP.NET MVC 5** web project with **E.F. 6.1.3.**
I use **IDbSet** and its method **Add** to insert new data in my database. I also use context to save changes.

```
protected IDbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
public DbContext Context { get; set; }

private void Insert(T item)
    {
        this.DbSet.Add(item);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When i insert new **item** in database 
Is there any **equivalent** way in this interface to Sql **Command.ExecuteScalar** ?
In other words **i need to get the Id** of newly inserted item (my Id is first column and first row in current table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need ExecuteScalar (<s>but you have to create your POCOs thru `context.Set<T>().Create()` method</s> *no, you dont have to, it works without proxy*)

```
class MyPoco 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get;set;}
}
...
var myPoco = context.Set<MyPoco>().Add(context.Set<MyPoco>().Create());
context.SaveChanges();
int newId = myPoco.Id;
```

However, if you have to have some direct store query, you can use [context.ExecuteStoreQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx) (its not on IDbSet, but on Context class)

```
var departments = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>
    ("select Name from Department where DepartmentID < @p0", 5);
```

**EDIT** *(after you added code :) ):*

You can add custom interface (or even base class) to your POCO with Id property:

```
public interface IId 
{
  int Id {get;}
}

class MyPoco
 : IId 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and update your Insert code like this:

```
private int Insert(T item)
 where T : IId
{
  this.DbSet.Add(item);
  Context.SaveChanges();
  return item.Id;
}
```

<s>*Note this doesnt work when you create your POCO simply by `poco = new Poco()` - this way, you give up lot of EF functionality (proxies), you have to use `IDbSet<T>.Create()` method)*</s> *It work.*

Or keep your `item` and take Id value after you send it to your `Insert(item)`:

```
var myPoco = context.Set<MyPoco>().Add(context.Set<MyPoco>().Create());
context.Insert(myPoco);
int newId = myPoco.Id;
```

Comment: I think the way with IId interface will be the best way for me because in fact i have entities and they are all inherits from BaseEntity class with single property of Id. Give me few minutes to add some code and try it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's all good but there is another problem... My method Insert is located in class ContactRepository and this class override virtual method in class BaseRepository. I cant change the return type from void to int because there more RepositoryClases that override this InsertMethod...

Comment: Ah, thats bad. Can you verify that you DONT have assigned your new ID right after you call Insert()? :) Maybe you dont need proxy for this - just save your poco to variable, call insert with it and look in debuger to ID of that poco - it is posible it will be set (after `SaveChanges()` of course) to actual value. Worth a try.

Comment: OMG MAN you were right ! ! The Id is set and i can see it through debugger on the fly after it save it in database. Thanks a lot. It save me a lot of work to reconstruct my code, cause i just starting to imagine how it will work with UnitOfWork design patter and two repositories one for Contacts entity and one for Phone entity :)) THANKS A LOT :)